# how get response in axios when api is steam like SSE (Server-Send Events)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js, axios

Environment: web browser, javascript.

I want to use post method to call sse api (**Server-Send Events**) like

https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create

```
 curl https://api.openai.com/v1/completions \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
      -d '{
        "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        "prompt": "Say this is a test",
        "max_tokens": 7,
        "steam": true,
        "temperature": 0
      }'
```

I did some research online, and found I couldn't use EventSource , because it doesn't support send post data.

So I write the code like this in the browser try to read text in steam.

I don't know if that's a good idea:

```
    const response = await axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/my-service/chat',
                    data: data,
                    headers: {
                        'SESSION_ID': 'Header-Value',
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        "Accept": "text/event-stream",
                    }
                    , responseType: 'steam',
                });
//TODO: read steam and convert to text
```

I appreciate any help you could provide. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I doubt this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution chose the `fetch-event-source` framework.

https://github.com/Azure/fetch-event-source

Here are some other alternatives：

JavaScript+axios:

```
axios({
  url: 'https://api',
  data: {
    prompt: 'json data'
  },
  headers: {
    'accept': '*',
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  method: 'POST',
  onDownloadProgress: progressEvent => {
     const xhr = progressEvent.event.target
     const { responseText } = xhr
     console.log("=====responseText======")
     console.log(responseText)
  }
}).then(({ data }) => Promise.resolve(data));
```

Server+Java code:

spring-server-sent-events: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-server-sent-events

```
 public void consumeServerSentEvent() {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080/sse-server");
        ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>> type
         = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>() {};
    
        Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> eventStream = client.get()
          .uri("/stream-sse")
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToFlux(type);
    
        eventStream.subscribe(
          content -> logger.info("Time: {} - event: name[{}], id [{}], content[{}] ",
            LocalTime.now(), content.event(), content.id(), content.data()),
          error -> logger.error("Error receiving SSE: {}", error),
          () -> logger.info("Completed!!!"));
    }
```